# Como inserir datas em uma tabela de um banco de dados usando PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um formulário onde preciso salvar as datas que são colocadas dentro das Inputs em uma tabela do banco de dados MySQL, mas como estou apreendendo agora PHP, estou com dificuldades, pois com o código que tenho sempre que aperta para enviar as informações o campo data fica zerado `0000-00-00` após o registro.

Preciso de um código PHP para fazer a ligação das informações de data, para nome e E-mail já consigo salvar normalmente.

Exemplo do que estou usando:

```
<html>
<head>
<Title>Exemplo</Title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Conecta.php" methodh="POST">
        Nome<input type="text" name="nome"/>
        E-mail<input type="email" name="email"/>
        Data de nascimento<input type="text" name="data_nasc"/>
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Este e o Código PHP que estou usando, porém só salva nome e email....

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "Cadastro";
$username = "Root";
$password = "xxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";

// RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !

$nome = $_POST ["nome"]; 
$email = $_POST ["email"]; 
$data_nasc = $_POST ["data_nasc"]; 
$data = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data)));  

$newslleter = "INSERT INTO newslleter (nome,email,data_nasc) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$data_nasc')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $newslleter)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $usuarios . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simples falta de atenção amigo, mas basta você corrigir aqui `$data = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data_nasc)));` e na hora de inserir você insere a variavel $data, no lugar de $data_nasc na query. `$newslleter = "INSERT INTO newslleter (nome,email,data_nasc) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$data')";`

Comment: Fiz a correção e consegui gravar os valores de data porém apenas colocando na <input/> o formato  Y-m-d ex:(2018/05/27), qual seria o procedimento para que eu pudesse colocar na na <input> o formato d-m-Y e gravar no banco Y-m-d ? Obrigado

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_nasc, '%d/%m/%Y'); isso retorna a sua data no formato d-m-Y

Comment: Poderia ser mais especifico,  preciso receber a data da input que vem no formato Dia/Mês/Ano e passar para o código que eu tenho --->
$nome = $_POST ["nome"]; 
$email = $_POST ["email"]; 
$data = $_POST ["data"]; 
$data = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data)));

 $newslleter = "INSERT INTO newslleter (nome,email,data) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$data')";