# Como mudar a data que vem do formulário Html como d-m-Y para o formato Y-m-d com PHP?

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldades no código PHP para gravar a data no meu banco de dados.
Tenho este código,

```
$data = $_POST ["data"]; 
$data = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data)));

$newslleter = "INSERT INTO newslleter (data) VALUES ('$data')";
```

Porém a data só e gravada no banco de dados caso o usuário dígite dentro da Input o formato: Ano/mês/dia (Y-m-d) do contrario se digitar dia/mês/ano (d-m-Y) a data fica zerada.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como inserir datas em uma tabela de um banco de dados usando PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309742/como-inserir-datas-em-uma-tabela-de-um-banco-de-dados-usando-php)

Answer (score 0):

Antes de mais nada, recomendo que de uma boa lida no manual do php http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/index.php . Você vai evitar muita dor de cabeça lendo e aprendendo um pouco das funções por lá :D

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST)) { //TEM ALGO NO POST?
        $data = $_POST["data"];

        //Explode transforma uma string num vetor, separando os elementos a partir do char específicado.
        $vetData = explode("-", $data);

        /*
            echo "<pre>".print_r($vetData)."</pre>";

            Exemplo da saída Array ( [0] => 27 [1] => 06 [2] => 2018 )
        */

        $data = $vetData[2]."-".$vetData[1]."-".$vetData[0];

        $newslleter = "INSERT INTO newslleter (data) VALUES ('".$data."')";
    } else {
        echo "Favor preencher a data antes de acessar a página";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Apresentou erro o código que você me passou, preciso de algo para receber no fomato Dia/MÊs/Ano e passar para o código que eu tenho --->
$nome = $_POST ["nome"]; 
$email = $_POST ["email"]; 
$data = $_POST ["data"]; 
$data = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data)));

 $newslleter = "INSERT INTO newslleter (nome,email,data) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$data')";

Comment: Certo, é / ou - amigo?

Comment: Qual o erro?  Tenta específicar

Comment: O código php não reconhece a data que e colocada dentro da input como dia/mês/ano e passa a data zerada para o banco de dados, insere a data certa apenas quando o e colocado na input o formato ano/mês/dia.   Pórem o código não apresenta um erro especifico apenas não repassa a data no primeiro formato de citei, se puder me ajudar

Comment: Tenta trocar o tipo do campo data, provavelmente você planejou ele como date, muda pra varchar.